# How to redirect in a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress 3.0 if I'm using "wp_redirect"( or Headers) everything its working, but if I'm redirecting in Wordpress 3.5 I get Headers already sent.
I've investigate the problem and I found out that Wordpress 3.5 outputs html 
How can I make a simple redirect from a plugin in Worpress 3.5 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use JS:

```
window.location.href = 'http://someurl/';
```

Comment: this is javascript, I wanna do it with php

Comment: on the other hand I guess I could check to see if headers are already sent using headers_sent function but it would be better if I could make the redirect from php